# How do I use System.Configuration namespace on Linux

Tags: linux, f#

I tried to deploy my F# project to a linux box today. Can't compile using fsharpc because I have no System.Configuration reference.

How do I fix that on Linux? Why isn't this DLL available?

Is there something else I can use to get the same effect, or do I have to write my own code for reading .config files on Linux?

Comment: Mono or .NETCore?

Comment: I think it's mono. I installed option 1 on this site: http://fsharp.org/use/linux/